# validates_uniqueness_of :username not catching case sensativity

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I just discovered that even with a validates_uniqueness_of :email, :username customers can create new accounts with different case similar values.

Examples:

```
username
USERNAME

email@email.com
EMAIL@EMAIL.COM
```

Is this by design or am I missing something?

I have this validate line in my model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :username
```

It does work as expected with similar values:

```
username
username
```

I'm using rails 3.2.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is by design.  **email@email.com** and **EMAIL@EMAIL.COM** are not the same string, what you want in your situation is to turn case sensitivity off.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false
```

Comment: Devin's answer is totally correct. I would add that if you are adding this to a production code base though that you will need to audit your data to normalize instances where this has already occurred or you may end up with weird behavior in the future.